# YouTube Reporting API Reports are blank

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm attempting to collect channel reports for a specific set of YouTube channels. I’m able to do this successfully for most (if not all) of the channels I’m interested in except one. All requests in the request flow to collect channel reports are successful with the only indication of an undesired result being that the reports for this problem channel only contain headers for the metrics and dimensions.

At present, I’m only interested in three channel reports, namely channel_basic_a2, channel_province_a2, and channel_demographics_a1. Here are the sample report urls for each report type that I was expecting to return a report that contains data.

channel_basic_a2 report url:
https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/media/CHANNEL/Vuk4_JY-UdgIDI5Fib445g/jobs/bd2e6b26-904f-4ad0-9aff-3df14993262e/reports/2323462937?alt=media

channel_province_a2 report url: https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/media/CHANNEL/Vuk4_JY-UdgIDI5Fib445g/jobs/08f7eec7-f2f7-4060-9b26-9ba9965d5b91/reports/2323288791

channel_demographics_a1 report url: https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/media/CHANNEL/Vuk4_JY-UdgIDI5Fib445g/jobs/0affb5ff-e795-431c-8d66-4be05fab3b28/reports/2323564263

Comment: Can you add the expected results and the responses of those requests? I can't understand well your question. Do you have permissions for querying the "problematic channel"? have you consider if the "problematic channel" has changed its settings and/or there is no data available due to has no activity?

Comment: Yes, I considered that the problematic channel might have some settings that cause this, but I have not been able to identify any such setting. The channel is also an active channel, so I eliminated the possibility of no data being available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a deeper look, I discovered that this is a case of mistaken identity. I was pulling data from a different channel (one that is actually empty) than I intended to.